# Obtain part of url in proxy balancer from one balancer member

Tags: apache2, url-rewriting, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-balancer

I have cluster setup of Apache server . Behind this I have 2 Jboss instances which is load balanced by apache.

The configuration look somewhat like the below

```
   <VirtualHost *:1111>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com

    DocumentRoot "/apps"
    ErrorLog "logs/https.www.example.com.-error_log"
    TransferLog "logs/https.www.example.com-access_log"
    LogLevel warn


    <Directory "/apps">
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>


    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify On


    SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile "/apps/apache/conf/ssl/int/proxy.pem"
    SSLProxyCACertificateFile "/apps/apache/conf/ssl/int/cert.pem"


    RewriteEngine On

    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, public"

   <Proxy balancer://2node-aa>

            BalancerMember https://app01:8089 route=node1
            BalancerMember https://app02:8089 route=node2

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /aa balancer://2node/aa stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
    ProxyPass /static balancer://2node/static stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid

    ProxyPassReverse /aa balancer://2node/aa
    ProxyPassReverse /static balancer://2node/static



    ProxyPass /1/aa https://app01:8089/aa
    ProxyPass /2/aa https://app02:8089/aa

    ProxyPassReverse /1/aa https://app01:8089/aa
    ProxyPassReverse /2/aa https://app02:8089/aa

    ProxyPass /bb  balancer://2node/rest stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
    ProxyPassReverse /bb balancer://2node/bb

    </VirtualHost>
```

In the url access certain part of the url i want it to be routed from second node i.e node2 of jboss.

e.g. if i am accessing `http://www.example.com/aa/login/login.jsp` i need this request to be process by node2 `app02` only.

Rest of the request should load balance as normal access. 
How do i set the apache to do it ?

I have tried lot of `rewrite`,`<Location>` and `ProxyPassMatch` none has worked so far.

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did try this but it does not work.


<Proxy balancer://2node-aa>

BalancerMember https://app02:8080 route=node2

</Proxy>
RewriteRule ^/aa/login/(.*)$ balancer://2node-aa$1 [P]

I had put it just above the balancer with two node.
Don't see any error in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below statement in the configuration file which resolved the issue.

```
<Proxy balancer://2node-aa>

BalancerMember https://app02:8080 route=node2

</Proxy>

RewriteRule ^/aa/login/(.*)$ balancer://2node-aa%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
```

This link help me.

[apache httpd mod_proxy load balancing with multiple virtual hosts url redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675536/apache-httpd-mod-proxy-load-balancing-with-multiple-virtual-hosts-url-redirectio)

-Thanks